# Dibujar varias figuras con canvas en java sin perder las anteriores

Tags: java, android, android-studio, canvas

Sigo trabajando en mi proyecto, pero me siguen surgiendo una duda tras otra

Bien, ahora tengo el código prácticamente funcional salvo lo más importante, y es que deseo que al pulsar la pantalla se vayan dibujando varias figuras en función de las opciones que tengo seleccionadas.

El problema, es que al pulsar la pantalla me borra la figura anterior y me dibuja la nueva donde pulso.

Sería posible que alguien me pudiera corregir el código, y decirme como puedo hacer para que al pulsar la pantalla repetidas veces, me siga dibujando figuras sin eliminar las anteriormente dibujadas ?

graciassssssss

código:

```
public class PaginaDibujo extends AppCompatActivity implements AccionBotones {

    RelativeLayout layout1;
    Dibujar fondoDi;
    Dibujar fondo;
    Desplazar fondoDe;

    Paint paint;
    //Path path;
    Path path;

    List <Path> paths;
    List <Paint> paints;

    Button btnCancelar;
    Button btnGuardar;
    Button btnCerrar;

    ImageButton btnColores;
    ImageButton btnFiguras;
    ImageButton btnTamano;
    ImageButton btnLinea;

    ImageView imgColores;
    ImageView imgFiguras;
    ImageView imgTamanos;
    ImageView imgLineas;

    Canvas canvas;
    //String circulo = "circulo";
    //String medida = "pequeño";

    float Xpush;
    float Ypush;

    float[] x;
    float[] y;
    float[] radio;

    String colorString, figuraString, tamanoString, lineaString;
    String color, figura, tamano, linea;
    String imagen;
    Bitmap bmp;

    float ancho;
    float alto;

    ImageView image;

    int contador = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pagina_dibujo);

        findViewById();

        paths = new ArrayList<>();
        paints = new ArrayList<>();

        //metodoOnCreatePintar();

        imgColores.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imgFiguras.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imgTamanos.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imgLineas.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        if(bundle != null){
            if (bundle.getString("Color") != null){
                colorString = bundle.getString("Color");
            }
            if (bundle.getString("Figura") != null){
                figuraString = bundle.getString("Figura");
            }
            if (bundle.getString("Tamano") != null){
                tamanoString = bundle.getString("Tamano");
            }
            if (bundle.getString("Grosor") != null){
                lineaString = bundle.getString("Grosor");
            }
            if (bundle.getString("imagen") != null){
                imagen = bundle.getString("imagen");
            }
        }

        if (contador < 1) {
            RelativeLayout layout1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout1);

            canvas = new Canvas();
            fondo = new Dibujar(this);
            layout1.addView(fondo);

            ancho = layout1.getHeight();
            alto = layout1.getWidth();

            if (canvas != null) {
                metodoCargarPanel(canvas);
            }
        }

        contador++;

        btnCancelar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        btnGuardar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                metodoGuardarLienzoComoImagen();
            }
        });

        btnCerrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        btnColores.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                metodoAgregarFragmentColores();
            }
        });

        btnFiguras.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                metodoAgregarFragmentFiguras();
            }
        });

        btnTamano.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                metodoAgregarFragmentTamanos();
            }
        });

        btnLinea.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                metodoAgregarFragmentLineas();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putAll(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void BotonDeAccion(int boton) {

       switch (boton) {
            case 0:
                imgColores.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imgColores.setImageResource(R.drawable.color_blanco);
                color = "blanco";

                if (figura != null) {
                    if (figura.equals("circulo")) {
                        metodoElegirCirculo(color);
                    } else if (figura.equals("cuadrado")) {
                        metodoElegirCuadrado(color);
                    } else if (figura.equals("estrella")) {
                        metodoElegirEstrella(color);
                    } else if (figura.equals("subida")) {
                        metodoElegirTrianguloSubida(color);
                    } else if (figura.equals("bajada")) {
                        metodoElegirTrianguloBajada(color);
                    }
                }

                if (tamano != null) {
                    if (tamano.equals("xs")) {
                        metodoElegirTanamoXS(color);
                    } else if (tamano.equals("s")) {
                        metodoElegirTanamoS(color);
                    } else if (tamano.equals("m")) {
                        metodoElegirTanamoM(color);
                    } else if (tamano.equals("l")) {
                        metodoElegirTanamoL(color);
                    } else if (tamano.equals("xl")) {
                        metodoElegirTanamoXL(color);
                    }
                }

                if (linea != null) {
                    if (linea.equals("5")) {
                        metodoElegirLinea_5(color);
                    } else if (linea.equals("9")) {
                        metodoElegirLinea_9(color);
                    } else if (linea.equals("14")) {
                        metodoElegirLinea_14(color);
                    } else if (linea.equals("17")) {
                        metodoElegirLinea_17(color);
                    } else if (linea.equals("20")) {
                        metodoElegirLinea_20(color);
                    }
                }

                break;
            case 1:
                imgColores.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imgColores.setImageResource(R.drawable.color_rojo);
                color = "rojo";

                if (figura != null) {
                    if (figura.equals("circulo")) {
                        metodoElegirCirculo(color);
                    } else if (figura.equals("cuadrado")) {
                        metodoElegirCuadrado(color);
                    } else if (figura.equals("estrella")) {
                        metodoElegirEstrella(color);
                    } else if (figura.equals("subida")) {
                        metodoElegirTrianguloSubida(color);
                    } else if (figura.equals("bajada")) {
                        metodoElegirTrianguloBajada(color);
                    }
                }

                if (tamano != null) {
                    if (tamano.equals("xs")) {
                        metodoElegirTanamoXS(color);
                    } else if (tamano.equals("s")) {
                        metodoElegirTanamoS(color);
                    } else if (tamano.equals("m")) {
                        metodoElegirTanamoM(color);
                    } else if (tamano.equals("l")) {
                        metodoElegirTanamoL(color);
                    } else if (tamano.equals("xl")) {
                        metodoElegirTanamoXL(color);
                    }
                }

                if (linea != null) {
                    if (linea.equals("5")) {
                        metodoElegirLinea_5(color);
                    } else if (linea.equals("9")) {
                        metodoElegirLinea_9(color);
                    } else if (linea.equals("14")) {
                        metodoElegirLinea_14(color);
                    } else if (linea.equals("17")) {
                        metodoElegirLinea_17(color);
                    } else if (linea.equals("20")) {
                        metodoElegirLinea_20(color);
                    }
                }

                break;
            case 2:
                imgColores.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imgColores.setImageResource(R.drawable.color_azul);
                color = "azul";

                if (figura != null) {
                    if (figura.equals("circulo")) {
                        metodoElegirCirculo(color);
                    } else if (figura.equals("cuadrado")) {
                        metodoElegirCuadrado(color);
                    } else if (figura.equals("estrella")) {
                        metodoElegirEstrella(color);
                    } else if (figura.equals("subida")) {
                        metodoElegirTrianguloSubida(color);
                    } else if (figura.equals("bajada")) {
                        metodoElegirTrianguloBajada(color);
                    }
                }

            if (tamano != null) {
                if (tamano.equals("xs")) {
                    metodoElegirTanamoXS(color);
                } else if (tamano.equals("s")) {
                    metodoElegirTanamoS(color);
                } else if (tamano.equals("m")) {
                    metodoElegirTanamoM(color);
                } else if (tamano.equals("l")) {
                    metodoElegirTanamoL(color);
                } else if (tamano.equals("xl")) {
                    metodoElegirTanamoXL(color);
                }
            }

            if (linea != null) {
                if (linea.equals("5")) {
                    metodoElegirLinea_5(color);
                } else if (linea.equals("9")) {
                    metodoElegirLinea_9(color);
                } else if (linea.equals("14")) {
                    metodoElegirLinea_14(color);
                } else if (linea.equals("17")) {
                    metodoElegirLinea_17(color);
                } else if (linea.equals("20")) {
                    metodoElegirLinea_20(color);
                }
            }

            break;
        case 3:
            imgColores.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imgColores.setImageResource(R.drawable.color_amarillo);
            color = "amarillo";

            if (figura != null) {
                if (figura.equals("circulo")) {
                    metodoElegirCirculo(color);
                } else if (figura.equals("cuadrado")) {
                    metodoElegirCuadrado(color);
                } else if (figura.equals("estrella")) {
                    metodoElegirEstrella(color);
                } else if (figura.equals("subida")) {
                    metodoElegirTrianguloSubida(color);
                } else if (figura.equals("bajada")) {
                    metodoElegirTrianguloBajada(color);
                }
            }

            break;
        case 4:
            imgColores.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imgColores.setImageResource(R.drawable.color_verde);
            color = "verde";

            if (figura != null) {
                if (figura.equals("circulo")) {
                    metodoElegirCirculo(color);
                } else if (figura.equals("cuadrado")) {
                    metodoElegirCuadrado(color);
                } else if (figura.equals("estrella")) {
                    metodoElegirEstrella(color);
                } else if (figura.equals("subida")) {
                    metodoElegirTrianguloSubida(color);
                } else if (figura.equals("bajada")) {
                    metodoElegirTrianguloBajada(color);
                }
            }

            break;
        case 5:
            imgFiguras.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            metodoElegirCirculo(color);
            figura = "circulo";
            break;
        case 6:
            imgFiguras.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            metodoElegirCuadrado(color);
            figura = "cuadrado";
            break;
        case 7:
            imgFiguras.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            metodoElegirEstrella(color);
            figura = "estrella";
            break;
        case 8:
            imgFiguras.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            metodoElegirTrianguloSubida(color);
            figura = "subida";
            break;
        case 9:
            imgFiguras.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            metodoElegirTrianguloBajada(color);
            figura = "bajada";
            break;
        case 10:
            imgTamanos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            metodoElegirTanamoXS(color);
            tamano = "xs";
            break;
        case 11:
            imgTamanos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            metodoElegirTanamoS(color);
            tamano = "s";
            break;
        case 12:
            imgTamanos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            metodoElegirTanamoM(color);
            tamano = "m";
            break;
        case 13:
            imgTamanos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            metodoElegirTanamoL(color);
            tamano = "l";
            break;
        case 14:
            imgTamanos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            metodoElegirTanamoXL(color);
            tamano = "xl";
            break;
       case 15:
           imgLineas.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           metodoElegirLinea_5(color);
           linea = "5";
           break;
       case 16:
           imgLineas.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           metodoElegirLinea_9(color);
           linea = "9";
           break;
       case 17:
           imgLineas.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           metodoElegirLinea_14(color);
           linea = "14";
           break;
       case 18:
           imgLineas.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           metodoElegirLinea_17(color);
           linea = "17";
           break;
       case 19:
           imgLineas.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           metodoElegirLinea_20(color);
           linea = "20";
           break;
        default:
            imgColores.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            imgFiguras.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            imgTamanos.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            break;
    }
}

public void metodoElegirCirculo(String color){
    if (color.equals("blanco")){
        imgFiguras.setImageResource(R.drawable.circulo_blanco);
    }
    else if (color.equals("rojo")){
        imgFiguras.setImageResource(R.drawable.circulo_rojo);
    }
    else if (color.equals("azul")){
        imgFiguras.setImageResource(R.drawable.circulo_azul);
    }
    else if (color.equals("amarillo")){
        imgFiguras.setImageResource(R.drawable.circulo_amarillo);
    }
    else if (color.equals("verde")){
        imgFiguras.setImageResource(R.drawable.circulo_verde);
    }
    else {
        imgFiguras.setImageResource(R.drawable.circulo_blanco);
    }
}

public void metodoElegirTanamoXS(String color){
    if (color.equals("blanco")){
        imgTamanos.setImageResource(R.drawable.xs_blanco);
    }
    else if (color.equals("rojo")){
        imgTamanos.setImageResource(R.drawable.xs_rojo);
    }
    else if (color.equals("azul")){
        imgTamanos.setImageResource(R.drawable.xs_azul);
    }
    else if (color.equals("amarillo")){
        imgTamanos.setImageResource(R.drawable.xs_amarillo);
    }
    else if (color.equals("verde")){
        imgTamanos.setImageResource(R.drawable.xs_verde);
    }
    else {
        imgTamanos.setImageResource(R.drawable.xs_blanco);
    }
}

public void metodoElegirLinea_20(String color){
    if (color.equals("blanco")){
        imgLineas.setImageResource(R.drawable.linea_blanca_20);
    }
    else if (color.equals("rojo")){
        imgLineas.setImageResource(R.drawable.linea_roja_20);
    }
    else if (color.equals("azul")){
        imgLineas.setImageResource(R.drawable.linea_azul_20);
    }
    else if (color.equals("amarillo")){
        imgLineas.setImageResource(R.drawable.linea_amarilla_20);
    }
    else if (color.equals("verde")){
        imgLineas.setImageResource(R.drawable.linea_verde_20);
    }
    else {
        imgLineas.setImageResource(R.drawable.linea_blanca_20);
    }
}

private void metodoCargarPanel(Canvas canvas){
    if (imagen != null) {
        InputStream imageStream = null;
        try {
            imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                    Uri.parse(imagen));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        int ancho = canvas.getWidth();
        int alto = canvas.getHeight();
        // Transformamos la URI de la imagen a inputStream y este a un Bitmap
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
        // Ponemos nuestro bitmap en un ImageView que tengamos en la vista
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, (0), (0), null);
    }
}

public void metodoSeleccionarFondoCanvas(Canvas canvas){
    int ancho = canvas.getWidth();
    int alto = canvas.getHeight();
    Bitmap bmp= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.avestruz);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, (0), (0), null);
}

private void metodoOnCreatePintar(){
    if (contador == 1) {
        canvas = new Canvas();
        layout1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout1);

        fondoDi = new Dibujar(this);
        layout1.addView(fondoDi);
    }
}

private void metodoOnCreateMover(){

    layout1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout1);

    fondoDe = new Desplazar(this);
    layout1.addView(fondoDe);
}

private void findViewById() {
    btnCancelar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCancelarDibujo);
    btnGuardar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGuardarDibujo);
    btnCerrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCerrarDibujo);

    btnColores = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnAbrirColores);
    btnFiguras = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnAbrirFiguras);
    btnTamano = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnAbrirTamanos);
    btnLinea = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnAbrirLineas);

    imgColores = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgColor);
    imgFiguras = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgFigura);
    imgTamanos = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgTamano);
    imgLineas = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgLinea);

}

private void metodoAgregarFragmentColores(){

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("codigo", "color");
    FragmentMenu fragInfo = new FragmentMenu();
    fragInfo.setArguments(bundle);
    getSupportFragmentManager().
            beginTransaction().
            replace(R.id.layout1, fragInfo).
            commit();
}

private void metodoAgregarFragmentFiguras(){

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("codigo", "figura");
    FragmentMenu fragInfo = new FragmentMenu();
    fragInfo.setArguments(bundle);
    getSupportFragmentManager().
            beginTransaction().
            replace(R.id.layout1, fragInfo).
            commit();
}

private void metodoAgregarFragmentTamanos(){

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("codigo", "tamano");
    FragmentMenu fragInfo = new FragmentMenu();
    fragInfo.setArguments(bundle);
    getSupportFragmentManager().
            beginTransaction().
            replace(R.id.layout1, fragInfo).
            commit();
}

private void metodoAgregarFragmentLineas(){

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("codigo", "linea");
    FragmentMenu fragInfo = new FragmentMenu();
    fragInfo.setArguments(bundle);
    getSupportFragmentManager().
            beginTransaction().
            replace(R.id.layout1, fragInfo).
            commit();
}

/*@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    Xpush = event.getRawX();
    Ypush = event.getRawY();

    //metodoOnCreatePintar();

    return true;
}*/

class Dibujar extends View {

    Path path = new Path();
    //path = new Path();

    public Dibujar(Context context){
        super(context);
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        if (color != null){
            if (color.equals("blanco")){
                paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            }
            else if (color.equals("rojo")){
                paint.setColor(Color.RED);
            }
            else if (color.equals("azul")){
                paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            }
            else if (color.equals("amarillo")){
                paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            }
            else if (color.equals("verde")){
                paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            }
        }
        else {
            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        }

        if (linea != null){
            if (linea.equals("5")){
                paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
            }
            else if (linea.equals("9")){
                paint.setStrokeWidth(9);
            }
            else if (linea.equals("14")){
                paint.setStrokeWidth(14);
            }
            else if (linea.equals("17")){
                paint.setStrokeWidth(17);
            }
            else if (linea.equals("20")){
                paint.setStrokeWidth(20);
            }
            else {
                paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
            }
        }

        if (figura != null){
            float medida = metodoCalcularMedida();

            if (figura.equals("circulo")){
                canvas.drawCircle(Xpush, Ypush, medida, paint);
            }
            if (figura.equals("cuadrado")){
                canvas.drawRect(Xpush, Ypush, medida, medida, paint);
                //canvas.drawRect(medida, medida, Xpush, Ypush, paint);
            }
            if (figura.equals("estrella")){
                metodoDibujarEstrella(linea, color);
            }
            if (figura.equals("subida")){
                float[] derecha = new float[] {200, 200};
                float[] arriba = new float[] {400, 200};
                float[] izquierda = new float[] {200, 200};
                canvas.drawLine(Xpush, Xpush, Xpush, medida, paint);
            }
            if (figura.equals("bajada")){
                canvas.drawRect(Xpush, Ypush, medida, medida, paint);
            }
        }
        else {
            canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        }

        paints.add(paint);
        path.moveTo(Xpush, Ypush);
        paths.add(path);
    }

    public float metodoCalcularMedida(){

        int medida = 0;
        if (tamano != null){
            if (tamano.equals("xs")) {
                medida = 50;
            }
            else if (tamano.equals("s")) {
                medida = 100;
            }
            else if (tamano.equals("m")) {
                medida = 150;
            }
            else if (tamano.equals("l")) {
                medida = 200;
            }
            else if (tamano.equals("xl")) {
                medida = 250;
            }
        }
        else {
            medida = 50;
        }
        float fMedida = (float) medida;
        return fMedida;
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent evento){
        int accion = evento.getAction();

        Xpush = evento.getX();
        Ypush = evento.getY();

        float medida = metodoCalcularMedida();

        switch (evento.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                break;
        }

        /*if (axion == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            accion = "down";
        }
        if (axion == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
            accion = "move";
        }*/


        //invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Precisamente estoy trabajando en algo similar a lo que buscas

Lo que hace el código, es almacenar en un array list las coordenadas donde vas pulsando y la medida del círculo, luego configura un paint que también guardará en otro arraylist, finalmente dibuja los círculos con los datos de ambos arraylist:

```
//claseDibujo que extiende de View
public class ClaseDibujo extends View {

    //creamos las variables para paint y path
    Paint paint;
    Path path = new Path();

    //creamos dos arraylist, unos para path y otro para paint
    List<Path> paths;
    List<Paint> paints;

    //creamos un canvas
    Canvas canvas;

    //creamos dos variables float para las coordenadas "x" e "y"
    float Xpush = 300;
    float Ypush = 300;

    //creamos una variable float para la medida de los círculos
    float medida = 100;

    //constructor de la clase
    public ClaseDibujo(Context context) {
        super(context);

        //instanciamos los arraylst
        paths = new ArrayList<>();
        paints = new ArrayList<>();

        //instanciamos el canvas
        canvas = new Canvas();
    }

    //método onDraw que recibe el canvas por parámetro
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        //bucle for que recorre al arraylist de path almacenados
        for (Path p : paths) {
            //por cada path almacenado (PathCircle), lo dibuja utilizando el paint que acabamos de configurar
            canvas.drawPath(p, paint);
        }
    }

    //método onTouch que recibe el evento por parámetro
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        //le damos el valor a las variables del punto donde tocamos la pantalla
        Xpush = event.getX();
        Ypush = event.getY();

        //creamos un método case en función de la acción que hacemos en la pantalla
        switch (event.getAction()){
            //si la acción es tocar la pantalla
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                //creamos un nuevo paint y le damos configuración (antialias, espesor, contorno y color)
                paint = new Paint();
                paint.setAntiAlias(true);
                paint.setStrokeWidth(12);
                paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
                paint.setColor(Color.RED);

                //agregamos el paint al arraylist
                paints.add(paint);
                //creamos un nuevo path
                path = new Path();
                //almacenamos la figura de círculo con los datos de las coordenadas y la medida del círculo
                path.addCircle(Xpush, Ypush, medida, Path.Direction.CW);
                //almacenamos el path en el arraylist de paths
                paths.add(path);
                //salimos
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                break;

        }
        //método invalidate
        invalidate();
        //retornamos true
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @el.trasgu, precisamente lo que estaba buscando